# Pig Latin, got ["appleay"]

Tags: ruby

I am working on a Pig Latin translator. My code below translated one word to pig latin fine before I added code to iterate. Now it gives `[appleay]` instead of `appleay`. I can't find why it's failing.

```
def translate(str)
  alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
  vowels = %w(a e i o u)
  consonants = alpha - vowels

  str = str.split(' ')
  str.map! do |word|
    if vowels.include?(word[0])
      word + 'ay'
    elsif consonants.include?(word[1])
      word[2..-1] + word[0..1] + 'ay'
    elsif consonants.include?(word[0])
      word[1..-1] + word[0] + 'ay'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str = str.split(' ')` is creating an array of string objects.  From what I can tell, you're trying to return a string of the result, not the array of words.  Try an input other than apple, like "apple orange banana".  Do you see what's happening there?

Try calling `str.join(' ')` after you iterate and see if it returns what you desire.

Read more about `Array.join` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)